# iPhone + minor memory leaks + application crashes

Tags: iphone, crash

I have developed an application, when I test for Memory Leaks using Instruments, I get very minor memory leaks. Yet my application crashes after some time.

Sometimes, it crashes even when I am testing on Instruments, and during that time there are very very few minor leaks.

What can be the issue?

I am having only 6 GB memory on my iPhone device. And the application running in continuos FOR LOOP for most of the time.

Regards,
Pratik

Comment: post a stack trace of the crash, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not necessary need memory leaks to crash application (assuming crash is caused by low memory). Try to find and improve most memory consuming parts in your programm. You can also implement `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` in your application delegate and release all unnecessary resources there to free memory.